# EmberJS, jQuery UI, and Grunt.

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, ember.js, gruntjs

I am integrating Emberjs and jquery ui. using the methods mentioned in http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/

Everything thing seems to be working ok.

The problem is following:

When I have

```
JQ = {};
```

to declare a new namespace I faced with this error (although it works fine on the browser)

*JQ is not defined*

when I declare the same variable as

```
 var JQ = {};
```

Grunt shows no errors but it stops working in the browser.

I looked into the combined code in the browsers it is like the following

```
function(){
  var JQ = {};
 }
```

....rest of the code

so I am sure it is declared but the browser don't mange to see it.

So I can't find out the problem? nor the solution

Best,
Mohammad

Comment: what are you running with grunt??..

Comment: I am running EmberJS application that suppose to integrate with jquery UI. http://emberportfolio.herokuapp.com/

Comment: ok..thats yeoman you are using...

Comment: i think issue may be just linting....add JQ to the globals...

Comment: also if you want to make JQ global..declare it as window.JQ = {}

Comment: it worked out, but jshint is still telling me that it is not defined

Comment: have added in answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make JQ global..declare it as window.JQ = {}

i think issue may be just linting....add JQ to the globals...

In orderto make sure jshint doesnt throw error..add JQ to the global list in .jshintrc file

Answer (score 0):

When you use *var JQ = {};* and the result is

```
function(){
  var JQ = {};
}
```

your variable is defined only in the scope of that function, which means that you can't use it outside of that closure. So, when you use *JQ = {};* your compiled file should contain:

```
function(){
  JQ = {};
}
```

which defines the variable in the global namespace. But you said that you got *JQ is not defined*, so I could suggest to check if you don't use the variable before its definition.

Comment: I think you hit the spot, your analysis is great. how I can make this variable global within a function because each code is included inside a function with grunt

Comment: If you skip the *var* infront of the variable it becomes a global variable. However, the error which you get *JQ is not defined* is not because the definition of the variable, but because it is used before that.